# Migrate local MongoDB database to remote server

Tags: mongodb

- Mongodb works perfectly on my local computer using codeigniter library
- But I want to migrate my database to the remote server
- mongodb version 3.0.15

First, I run this command

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin> mongodump --db plexus
2018-03-06T13:45:19.860+0500    writing plexus.system.indexes to 
dump\plexus\sys
tem.indexes.bson
2018-03-06T13:45:19.864+0500    writing plexus.user to dump\plexus\user.bson
2018-03-06T13:45:19.867+0500    writing plexus.user metadata to 
dump\plexus\user
.metadata.json
2018-03-06T13:45:19.871+0500    done dumping plexus.user (3 documents)
```

- Dump folder created

After this i run this command according to tutorial [link](http://edvinsantonovs.co.uk/how-to-migrate-local-mongodb-to-remote/) error occur connecting to db server: no reachable servers

mongo.tandonenterprise.com mysubdomain  http used port 80

```
  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongorestore --host 
  mongo.tandonenterprise.com --port 80 --username admin --password admin 
  ~/dump/plexus
  2018-03-06T15:35:47.574+0500    Failed: error connecting to db server: no 
  reachable servers
```

I didn't find any mongo.conf file I searching a lot in which they can set different things in mongo.conf file

Comment: Are you sure the `mongod` is listening on port `80`? That is usually the port for HTTP traffic.

Comment: i am not sure .

Comment: Where did you get port 80 from? Is it in the `mongod` config file? Do you have access to the machine at `mongo.tandonenterprise.com` to see if the process is running and one which port it is listening?

Comment: i search a lot and i found that http site usually used port 80

Comment: one thing more i cannot found any mongod config file in bin folder

Comment: Is the server linux or windows? Can you ask whoever installed mongodb on this server where it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166336/discussion-between-unknow-and-pete-garafano).

Comment: linux server and mongodb not install on my server